# Dynamically create a plane between 4 known points in Unity ARCore for Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to dynamically create a plane between 4 known points.  The 4 points are created by the user touching the phone screen and a cylinder is placed where they touched, very similar to HelloAR tutorial except with cylinders and not Andys.  This is working, the 4 cylinders get created.  In a hypothetical situation the user is going to create a square with the 4 points, let's say 2 meters by 2 meters. I then want to dynamically place a plane that fits into the 4 points (it doesn't have to fit exactly, just roughly). Using adb I have validated that the CreateBricks method is called and the plane is instantiated with the correct transform. I just don't see the plane get created.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GoogleARCore;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera firstPersonCamera;
    public Text anchorcount;
    public GameObject pointPrefab; //The cylinder prefab
    public GameObject patioPrefab; //The plane prefab
    public ArrayList pointArray;

    private int anchorCount;
    private bool m_IsQuitting = false;
    private bool brickCreated = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        QuitOnConnectionErrors();
        anchorCount = 0;
        pointArray = new ArrayList();
        brickCreated = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        _UpdateApplicationLifecycle();

        if (anchorCount < 4)
            ProcessTouches();
        else if(!brickCreated)
            CreateBricks();
    }

    private void CreateBricks()
    {
        try
        {
            brickCreated = true;

            Debug.Log("CreateBricks");

            float dist1 = Vector3.Distance(((GameObject)pointArray[0]).transform.position, ((GameObject)pointArray[1]).transform.position);
            float dist2 = Vector3.Distance(((GameObject)pointArray[0]).transform.position, ((GameObject)pointArray[3]).transform.position);

            Debug.Log("dist1:" + dist1.ToString());
            Debug.Log("dist2:" + dist2.ToString());

            GameObject prefab;
            prefab = patioPrefab;

            // Instantiate Andy model at the hit pose.
            var pointObject = Instantiate(prefab);

            prefab.transform.position = ((GameObject)pointArray[0]).transform.position;
            prefab.transform.position.Scale(new Vector3(dist1, 0.5f, dist2));

            Debug.Log(prefab.transform.position.x.ToString() + " " + prefab.transform.position.y.ToString() + " " + prefab.transform.position.z.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    void ProcessTouches()
    {
        Touch touch;
        if (Input.touchCount != 1 ||
            (touch = Input.GetTouch(0)).phase != TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Raycast against the location the player touched to search for planes.
        TrackableHit hit;
        TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon |
            TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

        if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
        {
            // Use hit pose and camera pose to check if hittest is from the
            // back of the plane, if it is, no need to create the anchor.
            if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) &&
                Vector3.Dot(firstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position,
                    hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit at back of the current DetectedPlane");
            }
            else
            {
                // Choose the Andy model for the Trackable that got hit.
                GameObject prefab;
                prefab = pointPrefab;

                // Instantiate Andy model at the hit pose.
                var pointObject = Instantiate(prefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);

                // Compensate for the hitPose rotation facing away from the raycast (i.e. camera).
                //andyObject.transform.Rotate(0, k_ModelRotation, 0, Space.Self);

                // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of the physical
                // world evolves.
                var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

                // Make Andy model a child of the anchor.
                pointObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;


                pointArray.Add(pointObject);
                anchorCount++;

                anchorcount.text = "Points: " + anchorCount;
            }
        }
    }

    private void _UpdateApplicationLifecycle()
    {
        // Exit the app when the 'back' button is pressed.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        // Only allow the screen to sleep when not tracking.
        if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking)
        {
            const int lostTrackingSleepTimeout = 15;
            Screen.sleepTimeout = lostTrackingSleepTimeout;
        }
        else
        {
            Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
        }

        if (m_IsQuitting)
        {
            return;
        }

        QuitOnConnectionErrors();
    }

    private void _ShowAndroidToastMessage(string message)
    {
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        if (unityActivity != null)
        {
            AndroidJavaClass toastClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.widget.Toast");
            unityActivity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
            {
                AndroidJavaObject toastObject = toastClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("makeText", unityActivity,
                    message, 0);
                toastObject.Call("show");
            }));
        }
    }

    void QuitOnConnectionErrors()
    {
        // Quit if ARCore was unable to connect and give Unity some time for the toast to appear.
        if (Session.Status == SessionStatus.ErrorPermissionNotGranted)
        {
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Camera permission is needed to run this application.");
            m_IsQuitting = true;
            Invoke("_DoQuit", 0.5f);
        }
        else if (Session.Status.IsError())
        {
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("ARCore encountered a problem connecting.  Please start the app again.");
            m_IsQuitting = true;
            Invoke("_DoQuit", 0.5f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `prefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(dist1, 0.5f, dist2)`?

Comment: I updated my code to this, thank you.  That didn't make the plane show up, I had to update the Instantiate call to make the plane the child object of one of the cylinders and it now shows up.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the above code was resolved by setting the parent of the pointObject variable in the Instantiate object.  The plane then showed up relative to the parent object.